# VBA Excel delete multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

This works

```
  mySheet.Rows(CStr(activeRow) & ":" & CStr(activeRow + deletedRowAmount)).Delete
```

This does not work

```
mySheet.Columns(CStr(columDelete) & ":" & CStr(columDelete + deletedRowAmount)).Delete
```

What I am missing here?

ERROR is **VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”**

Comment: What are the values of the variables?  What are they declared?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Variables are longs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns are A,B,C,... when used in a string as you are using them.  If they are numbers you will need to do it slightly different:

```
With mySheet    
    .Range(.cells(1,columDelete), .cells(1,columDelete + deletedRowAmount)).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Very useful piece of code. As a newbie it is hard to understand VBA illogical syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46178871/5448626) says is quite enough, but here is a way to go around it and make it easier:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Columns(GetColumnRange(2, 5)).Delete

End Sub

Public Function GetColumnRange(colStart As Long, colEnd) As String

    GetColumnRange = Split(Cells(1, colStart).Address(True, False), "$")(0) & _
              ":" & Split(Cells(1, colEnd).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

End Function
```

Try the `TestMe` function, it should delete the columns from `2(B)` to `5(E)`.

Comment: As this is maybe easier to understand, the fact that vba will need to parse the resultant string back to numbers it will add time, albeit a fraction of a second.  This is like changing your cars DC output to AC just to convert it back to DC to charge your phone.  If done in a loop it will make a difference in performance.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yup, a few fractions of a second could be lost.

Comment: It was just a FWIW comment, the OP may be willing for the time payoff if it is easier to understand and use for them.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I know :)

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I have so many methods already in place, so not convenient to make new ones :-)